# Need to set some default Value in my Dropdown using Jquery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set my first default value as **Homapage1 , but not able to do and my code is below.**

This is my XML for dropdown

```
<tabsOrder
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
                            composite="{Boolean}true"
                            fieldLabel="Add Tab Order"
                            metaType="text-single"
                            name="tabsOrder"
                            valueType="string[]">
                            <field
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container"
                                name="./tabsOrder">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <column
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <tabName
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
                                                emptyOption="{Boolean}false"
                                                fieldDescription="Select the Tab Name from dropdown"
                                                fieldLabel="Tab Order Name"
                                                listOrder="100"
                                                name="./tabName"
                                                options="HomePage Section,About Section,Leadership Section,Additional Section,Collaboration Section"
                                                selected="{Boolean}true"
                                                valueType="string">
                                                <datasource
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    sling:resourceType="dam/cfm/admin/components/datasources/optionrenderer"
                                                    variant="default"/>
                                            </tabName>
                                        </items>
                                    </column>
                                </items>
                            </field>
                        </tabsOrder>
```

Below is my Jquery/Javascript

```
function validatetabsOrderCards() {
            showHidetabsOrderFields();
            var isValid = true;
            var $multifield = $('coral-multifield[data-element="tabsOrder"]')
            var $multifieldItems = $multifield.children('coral-multifield-item');
                //$multifieldItems.find('coral-select[name$="/tabName"]').first().value('HomePage1');
            $multifieldItems.find('coral-select[name$="/tabName"]').first().prop('disabled', true);

            
            return isValid;
        }
```

Here I want to set the first default value as Homepage1 and I am trying below , but it is not working.

```
$multifieldItems.find('coral-select[name$="/tabName"]').first().value('HomePage1');
```

Can anyone please help me here.